# Stop web.config creation in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, iis-7, web-config

I know someone may complain that this should be posted in the wordpress site but this isn't necessarily a wordpress question/solution.

The issue is wordpress likes to create a web.config file which causes issues. A trick we use on linux is to 444 the htaccess so it can't be edited. But on Azure (IIS) this isn't possible to do the same on web.config.

In the meantime I've edited the core, changing this function:

```
iis7_save_url_rewrite_rules()
```

I see 3 possible options to solve this.

1. Make the web.config not writeable so wordpress can't edit it
2. Overwrite the function, if this is possible using PHP (currently I don't believe it is)
3. Using a wordpress hook/filter

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the source of `iis7_save_url_rewrite_rules()` the only solution I can think of is to remove the write access to `web.config`.  Wordpress is built to handle a lack of access to `web.config` cleanly so don't worry about errors there, just make sure that you get the correct rewrite rules in there somehow.

Also: There are no filter calls in this function that I can see so I highly doubt that you will be able to fix this with a plugin.